# Three Equal Columns in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than `768px` wide. I want to, that than `991px` wide but in `bootstrap 4`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you use bootstrap 3! you want this code fit to version 4???

Comment: yes. i need this in bs4

Comment: Are you comfortable with scss, this can easily be done ..

Answer (score 0):

Just chang scrips to bootstrap-4:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is code:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 768px wide.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use media-query to `991px`**
 **jsFiddle**:https://jsfiddle.net/9p3nws1h/

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {
     .col-sm-4{
        width:33.333333%!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: i know how to add a bootstrap 4 :D but I need, that The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than `991px` wide. (not 768px)

Comment: tell me if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options). It shows that the `lg` breakpoint is 992 pixels ...

[image]

Therefore, the markup is simply:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-4</div>
     <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-lg-4</div>
     <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-lg-4</div>
</div>
```

[Working demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/dUn1M7tchC)

Answer (score -1):

Please refer Grid options section in bootstrap documentation for information on the breakpoints in grid. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options

You are using col-**sm**-4 in your code and the breakpoint for **sm** is 540px.
Other options are

> **md** at 720px
>
> **lg** at 960px
>
> **xl** at 1140px

If you want to define your own breakpoints then write your own media css queries.

Answer (score -1):

```
In bootstrap 4, 991px resolution is not defined in media queries but then too if you want to add it, then you need to add it manually like this: 

Bootstrap provides 992px resolution which comes in ".col-lg-"

@media only screen (min-width:991px) {
  // Here comes your code
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This isn't bootstrap, but it's a demonstration of how straightforwardly you can achieve your desired effect, using CSS3 Flexbox and a single `@media` query.

**Working Example:**

```css
.row {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row div {
flex: 1 1 33%;
height: 100px;
}

.row div:nth-of-type(1) {
background-color: lavender;
}

.row div:nth-of-type(2) {
background-color: lavenderblush;
}

.row div:nth-of-type(3) {
background-color: lavender;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {

.row div {
flex: 0 0 100%;
}

}
```

```html
<main>
<p>The columns will automatically stack on top of each other when the screen is less than 991px wide.</p>

<div class="row">
<div>Column 1</div>
<div>Column 2</div>
<div>Column 3</div>
</div>

</main>
```